# kendo ui grid not displaying properly when integrated with bootstrap css framework

Tags: css, kendo-grid, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to know how to display the kendo ui grid when integrated with bootstrap css framework.

When integrating with bootstrap the grid columns are not aligning properly.

I found out that bootstrap uses the following code

```
*,*:before,*:after {
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

which disturbs the layout of the kendo ui grid.

I need to use bootstrap css framework in my project. It is mandatory.

I know that removing this css gives my output. I would like to whether there is any other solution to achieve my required output. If that solution exists then what it is?

The below is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/W4KLp/

The birthdate and age columns(line) alignment is disturbed as we can see in the layout.

Answer (score 3):

This definitely has to do with the fact Bootstrap and Kendo rely on different box models and the difficulties in making elements that rely on `box-sizing: border-box` intermix with those that rely on `box-sizing: content-box`.

In general, all the styling for Kendo is based on the standard `content-box` model. However, all the styling for Bootstrap relies on the easier to use `border-box` model. The biggest difference between the two is how padding, borders, etc. are treated. In `content-box` they're part of the width of an element, in `border-box` they're not.

Bootstrap assumes that of course you want to use `border-box`, and why wouldn't you! It helpfully sets *everything on the page* to use `border-box`, including the Kendo widgets. For it's part, Kendo knows that Bootstrap might set everything to use `border-box` so it sets everything back to `content-box` for Kendo widgets and *all their children*. So now if you nest anything Bootstrap related inside anything Kendo related you'll get the wrong box model. It's a mess.

I've tried a bunch of different hacks to try and mitigate this, but the fact of the matter is there's no good way to resolve it. This is the CSS code that I have found works best so far (it uses a CSS attribute selector, so it's a no-go for older browsers):

```
.border-box, .border-box * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    [class^="k-"] {
        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
        box-sizing: content-box;
    }
}
```

Then you set `class='border-box'` on any element that might get nested inside of a Kendo widget that you know will have Bootstrap content.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, my quick solutions is to add some normalize class for the parent container. For example :

```
<div class="container">
     // kendo ui grid mvvm
     <div data-role="grid">
     </div>
</div>

<style>
.container *,
.container *:after,
.container *:before
{
    -webkit-box-sizing : content-box !important;
    box-sizing : content-box !important
}
</style>
```